# Unable to deregister paraId on Kusama

Tags: kusama, crowdloan, parathread, auctions

We have a paraID locked after a completed Crowdloan, the auction has concluded in a no-winning state, and the parathread is still owned by the account manager.

Any explanation as to why the deposit is still locked?

Comment: This may be a bug in the runtime and it's being investigated

Comment: Hey @rob, following up on this. Is that confirmed a bug? I'm still unable to deregister the paraID

Comment: has this been fixed? we have a registered paraID that is not showing up and unable to deregister as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this issue has been fixed with this PR:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5451

You will want to remove the lock:

```rust
/// Remove a manager lock from a para. This will allow the manager of a
/// previously locked para to deregister or swap a para without using governance.
///
/// Can only be called by the Root origin or the parachain.
#[pallet::call_index(4)]
#[pallet::weight(T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(1, 1))]
pub fn remove_lock(origin: OriginFor<T>, para: ParaId) -> DispatchResult {
    Self::ensure_root_or_para(origin, para)?;
    <Self as Registrar>::remove_lock(para);
    Ok(())
}
```

So you can then call the `deregister` and get your deposit back:

```rust
/// Deregister a Para Id, freeing all data and returning any deposit.
///
/// The caller must be Root, the `para` owner, or the `para` itself. The para must be a parathread.
#[pallet::call_index(2)]
#[pallet::weight(<T as Config>::WeightInfo::deregister())]
pub fn deregister(origin: OriginFor<T>, id: ParaId) -> DispatchResult {
    Self::ensure_root_para_or_owner(origin, id)?;
    Self::do_deregister(id)
}
```